# Is it semantically correct to use the word 'ahead' when referring to moving in time?

Tags: meaning, semantics

**EDIT:** As in the questions title, is it semantically correct to use sentences such as "the concert was moved ahead in time as the stage was no longer available". To me, this makes sense, but is ambiguous in meaning - was the concert moved backwards or forwards?

Assuming this does make semantic sense: is there a way to remove the ambiguity and imply that the concert was delayed whilst maintaining the usage of the word ahead?

I've re-worded this entire question (thanks to [deadrats comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334562/is-the-sentence-i-travelled-ahead-in-time-grammatically-correct#comment765068_334565)).

---

**Original question:**
Is it grammatically correct to use the sentence "I travelled ahead in time"? If so, what would the meaning/interpretation be?

Based on the assumption that this is a valid sentence, is it then also valid to say "the concert was moved ahead in time"? Again, what would the interpretation of this sentence be, or is it ambiguous?

Comment: Yes - it would mean that you travelled into the future, like in a science-fiction story.

Comment: With that in mind, how about if the sentence was "the concert was moved ahead in time"? Would this mean that the concert has had it's original planned date moved into the future as well?

Comment: Changed my second comment to an answer.

Comment: Shorter form: "I waited."

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Yep, we all move ahead in time at the rate of sixty seconds per minute.  As judged by the clocks in our reference frame, of course.

Comment: I've edited my question, would appreciate any help with this!

Comment: Your revised Q has already been answered below by Max Williams, who said "You don't use "moved ahead in time" in any context other than the science-fiction story."  So why are you still asking whether "the concert was moved ahead in time ..." is correct? It is not! You could say "was moved forwards ...", but Max Williams's suggestions are better.  Also "in time" is superfluous, since you are clearly talking about time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that makes it sound like the concert travelled into the future like in a science-fiction story.

You would say "the concert was rescheduled to a later date" (or time if it was moved within the same day) or "the concert was moved to a later date".

You don't use "moved ahead in time" in any context other than the science-fiction story.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what if it was phrased "they moved the concert ahead (in time) as the stage was not available"?

Comment: Say "to an earlier/later time".  Besides the whole science-fiction aspect, it's not clear whether moving the concert "ahead in time" means "moving it to a later time" or "moving it to an earlier time".  Some people might interpret it in either way.

Comment: Appreciate the help so far. Honestly, I'm asking this question specifically to understand whether or not it is grammatically correct to use the word "ahead" when referring to time in a manner like this. So, despite ambiguity does the sentence make grammatical sense?

Comment: *Grammatical* means conforming to the rules of syntax, i.e., sentence structure. Your sentence is NP-V-Adv-PP, where the NP (Noun Phrase) is the Subject *I*, V (Verb)  is *moved*, Adv (Adverb) *ahead* modifies the verb in manner, and the PP (Prepositional Phrase) is licensed by the Adv. This pattern is grammatical.  Compare to *I moved ahead in line*. Whether it makes sense is a semantic issue, not a grammatical one. *I moved ahead in spatula* would seem to have no meaning, but it's as grammatical as either of our other examples.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I've reworded the question completely, would appreciate any help from you both.

Comment: @Oddism I've answered your question, I don't know why you keep rewording it, or which aspect of my answer you don't understand.  It seems like you're obsessed with finding a context where you can legitimately say "moved ahead".  I've explained that even if you could, it's confusing as it's not clear whether it would be moved to an earlier or later time.  Just don't do it.  Is someone holding a gun to your head or something?